# Modify the rendered string of a response in Grails 3 before sending to the client

Tags: html, servlets, grails

I need to create a benchmark report regarding whether in the grand scheme of things: minifying + GZIP dynamic HTML responses (generated through GSPs) on every request, which will lead to an additional overhead due to parsing of the generated dynamic HTML string then compressing using a Java library (which results to a smaller response size) is actually better than GZIP without minifying (which results to faster response time but a little larger response size). I got the feeling that this "improvement" *maybe* is insignificant, but I need the benchmark report to back it up to the team.

To do that, I modify controller actions like so:

```
// import ...MinifyPlugin
class HomeController {
    def get() {
        Map model = [:]
        String htmlBody = groovyPageRenderer.render(view: "/get", model: model)
        // This adds a few milliseconds and reduce few characters.
        htmlBody = MinifyPlugin.minifyHtmlString(htmlBody)
        render htmlBody
    }
}
```

But the Grails project has almost a hundred actions and doing this on every existing action is impractical and not maintainable, especially that after the benchmarking, we may decide to not minify the HTML response. So I was thinking of doing this inside an `Interceptor` instead:

```
void afterView() {
    if(response.getContentType().contains("text/html")) {
        // This throws IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
        OutputStream servletOutputStream = response.getOutputStream()

        String htmlBody = new String(servletOutputStream.toByteArray())
        htmlBody = MinifyingPlugin.minifyHtmlString(htmlBody)
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(htmlBody.getBytes())

        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8")
        response.setContentType("text/html")
        response.outputStream << byteArrayOutputStream
    }
}
```

But it seems that modification of the response body is impossible once it enters the `afterView` interceptor...? So is any other way to do this using Grails 3 Interceptors, or should I update every controller action we have manually and perform the modification there instead?

Comment: I think it would be better to do this in your servlet container or web server instead of at the app layer. If you use tomcat it has settings for this.

Comment: What Eric said is correct.  Separate from that... "But it seems that modification of the response body is impossible once it enters the afterView interceptor...?", that is right.  `afterView` is invoked after the response has been written, so it is too late.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I like to use Interceptors for.

The after() part of the interceptor can act on the model after it is returned from the controller (wherein 'before()' acts on the request before it is sent to the controller)

This allows you to manipulate all data for a set of endpoints (or one specific endpoint) prior to return to client

**If you are wanting to render to a view**, you do that in the interceptor rather than in the controller; you merely return data from the controller

Comment: The after() and before() methods do not initialize the content type yet and therefore I cannot filter out only the text/html responses.

Comment: If you need the contentType in the Interceptor just use request.getContentType(). The request has all info from the headers available for you.

Comment: The `contentType` is null when you use `getContentType()` inside the `before()` and `after()` methods. The `contentType` will only be initialized after passing through the `after()` and therefore only in the `afterView()` will you be able to get the actual `contentType`.

Comment: I dont know why you think that. I use it frequently in my HandlerInterceptors and it is working fine. Heres a class with it in it and working right now in several production sites: https://github.com/orubel/Beapi-API-Framework/blob/master/grails-app/controllers/net/nosegrind/apiframework/ApiFrameworkInterceptor.groovy . It worked fine in Grails 2/3 and it works in Spring/Springboot HandlerInterceptors

Comment: The content type can be null in the after() method, but appears to always be set if the request is XHR and is returning JSON. My guess is that if you render(x as JSON) it will set the content type immediately, but if you are rendering a GSP the content type is not set until afterView